# Expected value of hawkes process

Tags: point-processes

I’m studying hawkes processes and I find the formulation of the expected value of them in integration.
Actually I’m here to ask is there any closed form for expected value and other measures for multi-variate hawkes processes?

Comment: Can you say who is this guy, Fawkes, and how is his process defined ?

Comment: @JeanMarie The Hawkes process was first introduced in Hawkes (1971).The Hawkes process is a point process model with a conditional intensity
function that provides a change in intensity for each event occurrence and as
such the Hawkes process can be used to explain event clustering.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer.